# Agilidade de leitura MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação em MVC 4 que não possuí nenhuma operação de adição/exclusão/edição, ela apenas lê e disponibiliza dados (conforme filtros).

Os dados veem basicamente de 4 *views*.

- Sendo a primeira de cerca de 1,5 mil registros - leitura instantânea via query
- A segunda de cerca de 15 mil - leitura de cerca de 14 segundos via query
- A terceira de cerca de 30 registros - leitura instantânea via query
- A quarta de cerca de 1,3 mil registros - leitura instantânea via query

Cada `view` tem seu respectivo model. Consecutivamente, em cada `PartialView` necessária, chamo o domínio necessário.

Anteriormente trabalhava de forma parecida com esse exemplo:

```
var bdModelA = new SegundaViewEF(Contexto); // View da query de 14 segundos
var Todos = bdModelA.ListarTodos();
var Quantidade = Todos.Count();
var NF = Todos.Where(x => x.Tipo == "NF");
var NCC = Todos.Where(x => x.Tipo == "NCC");
var QuantidadeNF = NF.Count();
var QuantidadeNCC = NCC.Count();

foreach(var Item in NF){
// codigo aqui
}

foreach(var Item in NCC){
// codigo aqui
}
```

Notei lentidão, comecei a trabalhar assim:

```
var bdModelA = new SegundaViewEF(Contexto);
var Todos = bdModelA.ListarTodos();
var QuantidadeNF = 0;
var QuantidadeNCC = 0;
var Quantidade = 0;

foreach(var Item in Todos){
Quantidade++;
if(Tipo == "NF"){
QuantidadeNF++;
//Codigo aqui
}else if(Tipo =="NCC"){
QuantidadeNCC++;
//Codigo aqui
}
}
```

Continuou lento.

Gostaria de saber se a melhor prática é a descrita no primeiro exemplo ou no segundo e se há alguma limitação do MVC com relação a leitura de `view`, pois sempre trabalhei com leitura de tabela.

Eu chamo de um a três domínios diferentes em cada uma de minhas PartialView, sendo que a da maior query (14 segundos), eu chamo ao menos umas 4 vezes. Possuo cerca de 7 a 8 PartialView.

Minha aplicação demora cerca de 8 minutos para abrir (conexão via VPN) e 5 minutos via conexão direta.

O que posso fazer para melhorar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber se a melhor prática é a descrita no primeiro exemplo ou no segundo e se há alguma limitação do MVC com relação a leitura de view, pois sempre trabalhei com leitura de tabela.

Nenhum dos dois. É a repetição do já manjado erro de encapsular o contexto. Não vai funcionar direito porque assim você retira as opções em código de criar queries já otimizadas para cada consulta que você vai fazer. Do jeito que está, **todas** as leituras serão `TABLE SCAN`.

O que eu faria:

```
// var bdModelA = new SegundaViewEF(Contexto);
// var Todos = bdModelA.ListarTodos();
// var Quantidade = Todos.Count();
var Todos = Contexto.SegundaViewEF.AsQueryable();
var NF = Todos.Where(x => x.Tipo == "NF").ToList();
var NCC = Todos.Where(x => x.Tipo == "NCC").ToList();
var QuantidadeNF = NF.Count();
var QuantidadeNCC = NCC.Count();

foreach(var Item in NF){
// codigo aqui
}

foreach(var Item in NCC){
// codigo aqui
}
```

> O que posso fazer para melhorar?

Há outra coisa que pode ser feita: [Instalar o MiniProfiler.Mvc4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.Mvc4/) (serve pro MVC5 também) e conferir as consultas.

[Veja como configurar o projeto aqui](http://miniprofiler.com/).

Comment: Certo, obrigado Cigano. No MVC trabalhar com view ou tabela, da na mesma ? Acha que minha aplicação estava tão lenta pelos motivos citados?

Comment: O Entity Framework não analisa se o objeto é tabela ou view. Ele simplesmente executa os comandos de banco como um usuário normal faria. Sobre sua aplicação estar lenta, do lado dela o que estava errado já mencionei. Do lado da view, você terá que estudar o plano da consulta e ver o custo de cada operação.